# What's the recommended recording setup for better recognition using Sound Analysis createML model

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudioengine, createml

I'm trying to setup the `AVAudioEngine` with a tap node to record the microphone and send the buffer to recognize the category of the sound using SoundAnalysis/Create ML.

I'm using a model of type `VGGish` with Create ML with a window duration of `0.975 seconds`.
[image]

I have this current setup:

```
let listeningInputFormat: AVAudioFormat! = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatFloat32,
                                                                 sampleRate: 44100.0,
                                                                 channels: 1,
                                                                 interleaved: false)

tapNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024,
                               format: listeningInputFormat) { [weak self]  buffer, time in
  // Sending buffer to SoundAnalysis
}
```

I'm pretty rookie with this tool and I couldn't find any deep explanation on setting it up for optimal recognition.

I'm guessing the **Window Duration** is the sample duration used for the recognition, aka `0.975 seconds` in this case, Is there a recommended sample rate to use for the recording installTap buffer for an optimal recognition with this window's duration? *(0.975)*

I saw some people uses a buffer size of `44100` and others much lower like `1024`